# Domain Driven Design - Parent child relation pattern - Specification pattern

Tags: c#, java, .net, domain-driven-design

I was wondering which of the following is considered to be a best practice when dealing with parent child relationships.

1) The following example seems to be a common practice, but when creating an instance of a child, it will be in an invalid state as long as it is not added to the parent. Couldn't this lead to problems regarding validation etc.

```
public class Parent
{
    private ICollection<Child> children;

    public ReadOnlyCollection Children { get; }

    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;
        children.Add(child);
    }
}


public class Child
{
    internal Parent Parent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Child()
    {
    }
}
```

2) The next sample would take care that a child must always be related to its parent.

```
public class Parent
{
    private ICollection<Child> children;

    public ReadOnlyCollection Children { get; }

    public Child CreateChild()
    {
        var child = new Child();
        child.Parent = this;
        children.Add(child);
        return child;
    }
}


public class Child
{
    internal Parent Parent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    internal Child()
    {
    }
}
```

3) In the last example that child takes care of the relation to its parent itself.

```
public class Parent
{
    private ICollection<Child> children;

    public ReadOnlyCollection Children { get; }

    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;
        children.Add(child);
    }
}


public class Child
{
    public Parent Parent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Which pattern is considered the best? I believe that pattern 2 might be the best since then a child can never exist without a relation to its parent. This would make it easier e.g. when implementing a specification pattern that might do things like:

```
public class ChildSpecification
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(Child child)
    {
        return child.Parent.Children.Where(someCondition).Count > 0;
    }
}
```

The above specification can only work if a child has a parent.

What do you think? Do you know better ways? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

I definitely like suggestion number 2, but I think that it misses something important that is found in 3, namely that if a `Child` object cannot exist without a `Parent` it should take a `Parent` object in its constructor. Furthermore the `Parent` property on the `Child` class should be read only.
So you would end up with something like:

```
public class Parent 
{ 
    private ICollection<Child> children; 

    public ReadOnlyCollection Children { get; } 

    public Child CreateChild() 
    { 
        var child = new Child(this); 
        children.Add(child); 
        return child; 
    } 
} 


public class Child 
{ 
    internal Parent Parent 
    { 
       get; 
       private set; 
    } 

    internal Child(Parent parent) 
    { 
       this.Parent = parent;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I would do it like that as well, if the spec is that a Child should always have a Parent, and cannot be created without knowing its parent.
So, just a combination of 2 & 3.
+1

Answer (score 1):

Since I've just encountered the same design desissions and question still not marked as answered I'll post my vision on solution of this problem - maybe it'll help anyone. This solution actually perfectly viable for use with NHibernate.

```
public class Parent
{
    private readonly ISet<Child> _children = new HashedSet<Child> ();
    public virtual IEnumerable<Child> Children { get { return new ImmutableSet<Child> (this._children); }  }


    protected internal virtual void AddChild (Child child)
    {
        this._children.Add(child);
    }
}


public class Child
{
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; protected set; }


    protected Child()
    {
    }


    public static Create (Parent parent)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("parent");

        var child = new Child
        {
            Parent = parent
        };

        child.Parent.AddChild (child);

        return child;
    }
}
```

That's differs from your #2 option in a way that creation of the child object (and invalidating it's initial values) are gathered withing child object itself and not in parent object as you suggested in #2.

Tho one thing I'm not sure if it's considered bad design or not if we create child objects with personal factory method (`Child.Create`).

I hope someone with more experience in using DDD could comment on that.

Comment: It's my understanding that child entities should only be reference-able from the inside the aggregate. Meaning `Parent.CreateChild()` would be the appropriate public method while Child.Create() should be internal to the aggregate only. This is to ensure that only the Parent can create the child, and all invariants are observed by the parent. I could have a DDD misunderstanding though.

Comment: `child.Parent.AddChild (child);`: Please don't encourage this code, this would create a huge uncontrollable mess.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use option (1) - has always worked well for me. The important thing is not to expose the children collection itself to the outside world - the Parent should be able to mediate all the access. But I'm perfectly happy for a Child to be created elsewhere - I only care about it when it gets added to the Parent, and at this point it can be checked for validity etc. etc.

I don't understand your specification example: it seems like your ChildSpecification would return true if *any* of the parent's children has someCondition as true. Surely **IsSatisfiedBy(Child child)** should only return true if the specific child passed as a parameter satisfied the condition.

Comment: The specification pattern is about a special case I'm currently having in one of my projects. A child has a validity date range, which should'nt intersect with any other validity date ranges of any other child within the child collection. Would you consider this a specification for the parent?

Comment: I would probably implement this as a guard condition in the addChild() method of the Parent. The Parent would then disallow the add e.g. by throwing an exception. I probably wouldn't use a specification in this case.

Comment: But I need to check that on the UI as well. So when in exception is thrown, I would have to catch that. This isn't very elegant either. And afaik the good thing about specifications is that I could use it in lots of different scenarios like 1.) within my domain oe 2.) within a client application to pre-validate business logic. Or am I wrong?